# Vue.js Two Components share same data from service call

Tags: vue.js

I have two Vue components. One is hooked to the Data Store to get the data necessary to bind. It is displaying n details (records). The other component needs to share the same data. It is displaying the count on the records. How do I share information from 1st component.

I tried creating a global variable and set it in 1st component and use it in second component.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If these components is not related to each other (like parent-child) then you should use a global state using a Vuex to store your records and access them from different components.